# How to differentiate archive files from the regular files via .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net

I found `FileAttributes` enumeration a bit strange. For example, look at these attributes:

```
//
// Summary:
//     The file is a candidate for backup or removal.
Archive = 32,

//
// Summary:
//     The file is compressed.
Compressed = 2048,
```

Ok, I created a ZIP archive with some compression and hoped that it should have the `Compressed` attribute, but it has `Archive` instead which I thought should be related to some kind of system backup files or smth like this.

What I need is to have the ability to differentiate all archive types from the regular files via

```
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(sourcePath);
if (attr.HasFlag(/* ... */))
{
    //...
}
```

What should I do then?

Comment: the compressed attribute is for NTFS compression.

Comment: `FileAttributes` is the wrong place to look. Those are attributes related to the **file system**, they have nothing to do with the actual file **content**. I'm not aware of any .NET framework method to determine file content type, so you'll probably have to look for a library.

Comment: To add to @DanielA.White, these compressed files are usually denoted with blue text in the file explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining the type should be as straight forward as comparing file extensions (it's why we have them). e.g.

```
bool isArchive(string filename)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
    {
        var lowercaseExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename).ToLowerInvariant();
        return new[]{ ".zip", ".7z", ".rar"/*, ...*/}.Contains(lowercaseExt);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If I file doesn't follow this format, you're going to have to go another route:

1. Check the first bytes of the file to observe if the file follows an expected format.
2. Run an extraction library against the file and catch exceptions (though this is certainly error-prone and ugly).

Answer (score 1):

The attributes of a file have nothing to do with its contents. The Archive flag is [supposed to determine](https://superuser.com/questions/44812/windows-explorers-file-attribute-column-values) if a file has changed since it was last backed up.